# Can one access the iTunes Store Wish List via either of the two iOS app stores?

Tags: ios-appstore, itunes-store

I use the "My Wish List" feature in the iTunes Store to keep track of music, movies, and apps that I discover via various RSS feeds, curating them for later purchase. Can I view my "Wish List" in either the "App Store" or "iTunes" apps in iOS? If so, where can this feature be found?

Comment: Wait, there's a wish list function?!?!  Thanks, I had *no* idea...

Comment: @stuffe Yeah. It's in the "Quick Links" sidebar on the right, when you're on your iTunes Store home page. When you click and hold the down-triangle near a potential purchase, "Add To Wish List" comes up as an option along with "Like," "Post," "Gift This Song," et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment, but when iOS 7 is released later, the wishlist feature will be available using a button in the corner of the app ([source](http://www.cultofmac.com/235199/use-ios7s-new-app-store-wishlist-feature-to-manage-your-app-wants-ios-tips/))